# Smartwatch 2 Vertical Scroll Layout in Gallery View

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

i'm developing a smartwatch2 extension and using gallery view in my layout, how can i enable vertical scroll in gallery view item ? I want to add content more than SW2 heigt and user will scroll through bottom. Also will be able to swipe left and rigth in gallery view.

Left and right swipes are OK in gallery view, but could not enable a scroll view in a gallery view item. How can user scroll in gallery view, thanks for ideas / layout sample.

Edit : I just want to a view that can be scrolled vertically. This can be done in listView for Smart Watch. But I need it in a sample layout not using a listView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should show (send from the phone to the smartwatch) only the extract of the image, that should currently be visible. Then manually catch swipe-up/down events and update the visible part of the image manually (by sending another image from the phone to the smartwatch).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i'm showing only image, also text view with layouts inside gallery view. There will be also text on view, text size can be changed from view to view. 

I need a vertical scroll just like in listview  in sw2.